# The process cannot access the file 'file.csv' because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, csv

I have a code which process each file in a folder and send the data in the file to SQL Database and then deletes the file. But often i get this Exception "The process cannot access the file 'file.csv' because it is being used by another process." Please can anyone point me out in the right direction, will really appreciate that.

The code is shown below :

```
    Dim dirinfo As DirectoryInfo
    Dim allFiles() As FileInfo

    dirinfo = New DirectoryInfo("E:\SQLUPDATE\CAC")
    allFiles = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.csv")
    If allFiles.Length <> 0 Then
        Try
            For Each fl As FileInfo In allFiles
                'MsgBox(fl.FullName.ToString())
                Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(SQL_con2)
                Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fl.FullName)
                Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
                Dim value() As String = line.Split(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(44))
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
                Dim row As DataRow
                For Each dc As String In value
                    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(dc))
                Next

                While Not sr.EndOfStream
                    value = sr.ReadLine.Split(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(44))
                    If (value.Length = dt.Columns.Count) Then
                        row = dt.NewRow
                        row.ItemArray = value
                        dt.Rows.Add(row)
                    End If

                End While
                Dim bc As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)
                bc.DestinationTableName = "[DB].[dbo].[CAC_LData]"
                bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count
                con.Open()
                bc.WriteToServer(dt)
                bc.Close()
                con.Close()
                sr.Close()
                System.IO.File.Delete(fl.FullName)
                sr.Dispose()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: Try swapping the line with `File.Delete` and the line `sr.Dispose`.  If that's not it, then please tell us which line is generating the exception.

Comment: The problem is basically FTP client is writing files to this folder at the very same time this function tries to process the file and because by that time if FTP client has not finished writing the file, the collision occurs and it reads the files ok but when it comes to delete it throws this exception. So i need some kind of check to see if the file is released by the FTP client and then proceed.